# Camera app which allows enhanced visualization of imperfections via real-time filters

Tags: android, video, photography, camera

Is there a camera app for Android which allows for real time (not post-save) filters which adjust contract, levels, curves, performs equalize (like in Photoshop), or otherwise which could help visualize imperfections in objects which may not have been easily noticeable by the naked eye on casual inspection. For example, two slightly different shades of paint, stains, etc.

Comment: This app may be your best bet: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hd.camera.filter